# List of domains used by Google Maps API Family (Firewall Config)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-maps, google-play-services, geolocation, firewall

our corporate config firewall to allow Android Phone use 
App to Map Location , our programmer use fused location provider API (GPS, Network etc) to Map , but the Phont is in the internal network,and deny access the internet , except for a few allowed sites (white list, *.google.com) and internal network,

we need the IP addresses/Domain List or range of IPs that Google uses for this domain. Is this information provided anywhere ?
we check on https://developers.google.com/, but can not found any thing we need. we search some forum , get some ip & domain but not sure its work,

◦mt0.google.com
◦mt0.googleapis.com
◦mt1.google.com
◦mt1.googleapis.com
◦khm0.google.com
◦khm0.googleapis.com
◦khm1.google.com
◦khm1.googleapis.com

please help and thank you.

by Lain
drupal2018@gmail.com

Comment: Did you find answer for your question?